# A Conference Calling App

Tags: android, voip, sinch, android-sinch-api

I was working on a VOIP app two days ago and was successful in implementing a normal App to App calling using [Sinch](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-app-to-app-voip-tutorial/). The app is working fine. When I started I saw in their docs that they supported Conference Calling.

Now upon detailed analysis I came to know that android does not have a conference calling option in their sdk.

So now my question is : Is there any service providers who offer easy setup and usage for conference calling over the net? Please attach the appropriate link to their tutorials.

Is it possible to implement conference calling using Sinch itself? If so how?

Comment: Asking for tutorials and links is off-topic for StackOverflow. You are welcome to [edit] to reword your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinch does have conference calling in the SDK on the callclient use callConference(String conferenceId)

Comment: It is not resolving  `callConference` in my app. What are the header files that I need to add?

Comment: I have successfully implemented conference calling thanks for your help. Can help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127571/add-clients-to-conference-call-in-sinch)