# Add clients to conference call in Sinch

Tags: android, voip, sinch, android-sinch-api

I have implemented the Conference Call using Sinch and it is working perfectly. Now my requirement is I should be able to add clients to the conference call. According to the Sinch docs I can make users to connect to the same conference room only when all the users use the same conference room name.

What I am trying to achieve is to have one user create a conference room and add users to that room as he wishes. Can this be achieved , if so how?

All answers are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the ConferenceCallout in the restapi, there you can add users with conferenceid and userid
https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#Callouts

Comment: Is there no function to do this. I am new to `REST` api and I am not sure how to integrate it in my app.

Comment: What I am asking is there is a function to create a conference call like  `callClient.callConference("<conferenceId>");` . Is there any functions that will achieve the functionality I need. As I said before I have no idea about `REST` and I have not worked with it before. If there is any samples that I can look into?? @cjensen

Comment: not in the client sdks, sorry. Only serverside. But its a good idea that I will tell the product team about

Comment: Thank you for the reply @cjensen.  I am looking forward to see this feature implemented in Sinch